# I made a simple Progressive Web App, but when i run offline the cache file is being deleted automatically. how do i solve that?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

here is my sw.js (service worker.js)

```
    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
      console.log('SW Installed');
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('static')
          .then(function (cache) {
            // cache.add('/');
            // cache.add('/index.html');
            // cache.add('/src/js/app.js');
            cache.addAll([
                    "index.html",
                    "style.css",
                    "bootstrap.min.js",
                    "bootstrap.min.css",
                    "images/icon.png",
                    "images/golden.jpg",
                    "images/golden1.jpg",
                    "images/golden2.jpg",
                    "images/golden3.jpg",
                    "images/golden4.jpg",
                    "images/golden5.jpg",
            ]);
          })
      );
    });

self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
  console.log('SW Activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
          return res;
        } else {
          return fetch(event.request);
        }
      })
  );
});
```

here is my app.js

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    window.onload = () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
            .then(function (argument) {
                // body...
                console.log('serviceWorker registered');
            });
    };

}
```

[as you can see the cache file is there when the app is online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqtS.jpg)

[but as soon as its offline the cache file gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBQd2.jpg)

Please help, I let the cache store in the browser for a while, then I opened it again to check whether the service worker is working. it's is working but as soon as I go offline both service worker and the cache is deleted, and the browser shows you are offline.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the root path to your cache:

```
 cache.addAll([
            "/",
            "index.html",
            "style.css",
            ...
 ]);
```

Comment: You didn't include the root "/" path as shown in my code same sample above.